# For which integers $n, 3\leq n\leq 11$ is there only one group of order $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is the way of thinking in this question:

> [image]

similar to the way of thinking in that question? actually I do not know how to solve the first question, any hint will be appreciated.

> [image]

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: For the first one: the cyclic group of order $n$ is always an example of a group of order $n$.  So for which $n$ is every group of order $n$ cyclic?

Comment: @Surb any hint for solving the first question will be appreciated :).

Comment: @Idonotknow: The solution of question 49 is the hint ! What else do you need ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Surb  I do not know your previous knowledge, I have asked in my post if it is a hint or no, and u answered now, thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a multiple choice exam, you should always work with the answers they give you. For instance, there is only one group of order $p$ (up to isomorphism) for any prime $p$, so this leaves only (B), (C), and (E) as possible correct answers.

And since $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ are non-isomorphic groups of order $9$, it follows that (C) and (E) are incorrect, so the answer is (B).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the general result:  There is *only* one group of order $n$ *iff* $gcd(n,\phi(n))=1$. $\phi$ being Eular's totient function.